# Tree recursion on python

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following tree algorithm which prints the conditions for each leaf:

```
def _grow_tree(self, X, y, depth=0):
    # Identify best split
    idx, thr = self._best_split(X, y)

    # Indentation for tree description
    indent = "    " * depth

    indices_left = X.iloc[:, idx] < thr
    X_left = X[indices_left]
    y_left = y_train[X_left.reset_index().loc[:,'id'].values]

    X_right = X[~indices_left]
    y_right = y_train[X_right.reset_index().loc[:,'id'].values]

    self.tree_describe.append(indent +"if x['"+ X.columns[idx] + "'] <= " +\
                             str(thr) + ':')
    # Grow on left side of the tree  
    node.left = self._grow_tree(X_left, y_left, depth + 1)

    self.tree_describe.append(indent +"else: #if x['"+ X.columns[idx] + "'] > " +\
                         str(thr) + ':')
    # Grow on right side of the tree
    node.right = self._grow_tree(X_right, y_right, depth + 1)

    return node
```

This produces the following print for a particular case:

```
["if x['VAR1'] <= 0.5:",
 "    if x['VAR2'] <= 0.5:",
 "    else: #if x['VAR2'] > 0.5:",
 "else: #if x['VAR1'] > 0.5:",
 "    if x['VAR3'] <= 0.5:",
 "    else: #if x['VAR3'] > 0.5:"]
```

How could I obtain the following output?:

```
["if x['VAR1'] <= 0.5:",
 "    if x['VAR1'] <= 0.5&x['VAR2'] <= 0.5",
 "    else: #if x['VAR1'] <= 0.5&x['VAR2'] > 0.5:",
 "else: #if x['VAR1'] > 0.5:",
 "    if x['VAR1'] > 0.5&x['VAR3'] <= 0.5:",
 "    else: #if x['VAR1'] > 0.5&x['VAR3'] > 0.5:"]
```

Comment: Didn't you make the indentation because you didn't want this output? Because now indent shows which item is a child of another, and now you want to repeat the `x['VAR1'] <= 0.5`/`x['VAR1'] > 0.5` parts to show that.

Comment: Initially yes, but now I intend to use the pandas query function to create leaf columns based on conditions and the first way is not practical. I need for each leaf to have all the conditions.

Comment: So just forward it like you did with depth. Depth grows +1, description elements will grow with conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a new argument to your function, which will have the string with higher-level condition(s) that need to be added to each deeper conditions:

I would also suggest using `.format()` for your string building:

```
def _grow_tree(self, X, y, depth=0, descr=""):

    idx, thr = self._best_split(X, y)

    indent = "    " * depth

    cond = "x['{}'] <= {}{}".format(X.columns[idx], thr, descr)
    self.tree_describe.append("{}if {}:".format(indent, cond))

    node.left = self._grow_tree(X_left, y_left, depth + 1, " & " + cond)

    cond = "x['{}'] > {}{}".format(X.columns[idx], thr, descr)
    self.tree_describe.append("{}else: #if {}:".format(indent, cond))

    node.right = self._grow_tree(X_right, y_right, depth + 1, " & " + cond)

    return node
```